# Bulk API Data Load taking more than 5 minutes to process Inconsistently

Tags: bulk-api

I have an issue in Bulk API Data load jobs which is taking sometimes more than 5 and 10 minutes to process even single record.
Basically we are migrating from Siebel to Salesforce and for now, we still have retained Siebel and Integrated to Salesforce via Mule ESB. So every 5 minutes, Mule process fetches updated and new records from Siebel and sends to Salesforce via Connector. If Salesforce Batch Job doesn't respond within 5 minutes, then it just updates as an Error. 
Usually Salesforce Bulk Data Load job processes in seconds but frequently like once or twice in a day, it is taking 6, 10, 12 minutes to process even 1 or 2 records.
if anybody else have encountered this kind of issue, please help me to figure out how to move forward, from where to debug.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bulk API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/) is optimized for loading or deleting large sets of data. You send a number of batches to the server and Salesforce processes the batches in the background (asynchronous process).

Since your request will be put into an [asynchronous queue](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Asynchronous_Processing_in_Force_com) (which can contain requests from multiple organizations), **you have no influence on when the process will kick off**. Sometimes this can be seconds, sometimes minutes.

Comment: Oh, So we cannot control it anyway and there is no work around to avoid it right.

Comment: Not using the Bulk API, but you could have at look at SOAP API which communicates synchronous.

Answer (score -1):

You might be hitting some of the BULK API usage limits for certain batch sync between siebel & salesforce which is encountering the error.

Please see the below link on BULK api usage limit:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_concepts_limits.html

You must verify if you get same sort of error message if you try to use SOAP API.

Comment: But we are not getting any error message. Same Bulk API works in seconds sometimes for 20 records but takes minutes sometimes for single record. So it's just based on Server load i feel.